# LUISGen throws exception when generating cs classes from json

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to generate cs calsses from json which I exported from luis.ai for one of my luis App.
But when I run the command `LUISGen myLuisApp.json -cs myClassName` I get below error on commandline
[Snapshot of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWgJe.png)

below is the json I got from luis.ai

```
{


"luis_schema_version": "7.0.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "myBotName",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "tokenizerVersion": "1.0.0",
  "patternAnyEntities": [],
  "regex_entities": [],
  "phraselists": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "patterns": [],
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "ApproveAllTasksOnMe"
    },
    {
      "name": "ApproveTask"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetApprovedTasks"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetCompletedTasks"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetLastApprovedTask"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetLastNTasks"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetLastRejectedTask"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetRejectedTasks"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetTaskDetails"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetTasks"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetTotalPendingTasks"
    },
    {
      "name": "GetTotalTasksCompleted"
    },
    {
      "name": "None"
    },
    {
      "name": "RejectAllTasksOnMe"
    },
    {
      "name": "RejectTask"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "Application",
      "children": [],
      "roles": [],
      "features": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Email",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "AssignedTo",
          "children": [],
          "features": []
        },
        {
          "name": "InitiatedBy",
          "children": [],
          "features": []
        }
      ],
      "roles": [],
      "features": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "AssignedTo",
          "children": [],
          "features": []
        },
        {
          "name": "InitiatedBy",
          "children": [],
          "features": []
        }
      ],
      "roles": [],
      "features": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Status",
      "children": [],
      "roles": [],
      "features": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Workspace",
      "children": [],
      "roles": [],
      "features": []
    }
  ],
  "hierarchicals": [],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [],
  "prebuiltEntities": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "all approved tasks",
      "intent": "GetApprovedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "all tasks",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "approve all",
      "intent": "ApproveAllTasksOnMe",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "approve task",
      "intent": "ApproveTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get all tasks i approved",
      "intent": "GetApprovedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get all tasks i rejected",
      "intent": "GetRejectedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get last 5 tasks",
      "intent": "GetLastNTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get last approved task",
      "intent": "GetLastApprovedTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get last rejected task",
      "intent": "GetLastRejectedTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get task details",
      "intent": "GetTaskDetails",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "get tasks pending on me",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 21,
          "endPos": 22,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 21,
              "endPos": 22,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "how man tasks are pending on me",
      "intent": "GetTotalPendingTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "how many tasks are assigned to me",
      "intent": "GetTotalPendingTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "how many tasks i closed today",
      "intent": "GetTotalTasksCompleted",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "how many tasks were completed by me",
      "intent": "GetTotalTasksCompleted",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "last 7 tasks",
      "intent": "GetLastNTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "last approved task",
      "intent": "GetLastApprovedTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "last task i approved",
      "intent": "GetLastApprovedTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "last task i rejected",
      "intent": "GetLastRejectedTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "list my tasks",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 5,
          "endPos": 6,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 5,
              "endPos": 6,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "number of tasks closed",
      "intent": "GetTotalTasksCompleted",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "reject all",
      "intent": "RejectAllTasksOnMe",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "reject all my tasks",
      "intent": "RejectAllTasksOnMe",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "reject all tasks",
      "intent": "RejectAllTasksOnMe",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "reject this task",
      "intent": "RejectTask",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show all completed tasks",
      "intent": "GetCompletedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show all done tasks",
      "intent": "GetCompletedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show all tasks approved by me",
      "intent": "GetApprovedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show done tasks",
      "intent": "GetCompletedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show how many tasks are closed",
      "intent": "GetTotalTasksCompleted",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show last 2 tasks",
      "intent": "GetLastNTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show my tasks",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 5,
          "endPos": 6,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 5,
              "endPos": 6,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "show tasks i took action on",
      "intent": "GetCompletedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "show tasks pending on me",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 22,
          "endPos": 23,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 22,
              "endPos": 23,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "tasks assigned to me",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 18,
          "endPos": 19,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 18,
              "endPos": 19,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "tasks i rejected",
      "intent": "GetRejectedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "tasks pending on me",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 17,
          "endPos": 18,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 17,
              "endPos": 18,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "tasks rejected by me",
      "intent": "GetRejectedTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "tasks waiting for my attention",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 18,
          "endPos": 19,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 18,
              "endPos": 19,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "tasks waiting on me",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 17,
          "endPos": 18,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 17,
              "endPos": 18,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "today's priorities",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "total tasks for me",
      "intent": "GetTotalPendingTasks",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "what are my tasks for the day",
      "intent": "GetTasks",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "Name",
          "startPos": 9,
          "endPos": 10,
          "children": [
            {
              "entity": "AssignedTo",
              "startPos": 9,
              "endPos": 10,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "settings": []
}
```

when run the same command with of the [json from examples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/13.core-bot/cognitiveModels/FlightBooking.json) it generated the classes without any error.

Can anybody help me understand what I might be doing wrong or if I am missing something?

I have installed LUISGen with below comand `dotnet tool install --global LUISGen --version 2.2.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would say 'make sure you're using the most up-to-date version of the tool', but
`LUISGen` is deprecated (legacy tool). The new botframework-cli was designed to replace legacy standalone tools. I don't think you're missing anything, but it hasn't been updated in almost a year.

The botframework-cli has a similar command: `bf luis:generate:cs` meant to generate CS classes on LUIS models.

https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/blob/main/packages/luis/README.md#bf-luisgeneratecs